# Firebase / AngularFire - Get Last Object Key By Datetime When Syncing Data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I currently have the following data structure within my Firebase DB:

```
-myUsername
    -5-31-2016 10:30:24 PM
        -message: 'first message'
        -timestamp: 1464748224
    -5-31-2016 10:34:26 PM
        -message: 'second message'
        -timestamp: 1464748466
    -5-31-2016 10:55:01 PM
        -message: 'third message'
        -timestamp: 1464749701
```

The above powers a chat application where each key underneath `myUsername` represents a message that the user has sent - with the datetime of the message acting as the key name.  In addition to the message key underneath the datetime object, there is also a `timestamp` key - this is the the UNIX timestamp of when the message was sent.

My end goal is to get the last chat message sent by an user.  I do not know the datetime of this last message so it will have to be discerned from the `myUsername` object.  I am currently using the following to do this:

```
$scope.getUsernameLastMessage = function(userName){
    var ref = new Firebase(firebaseConstants.url + 'messages/' + username);
    $scope.authWithFirebase(ref);
    var sync = $firebase(ref.orderByChild('timestamp'));
    return sync.$asArray();
};
```

This will return the entire message history of an user with the oldest message at array index 0.  I only want the last message.  I will run this function up to dozens of times (I need to get the last message sent by dozens of users) so would prefer to not download and sync the entire message history for an user, but rather just the last message.  I also noticed that `$asArray()` limits the size of the array returned to 400  - so if I have a user with more than 400 messages sent, the newest messages are truncated from the results returned.

Is there a way to get the latest object under `myUsername` in an efficient manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into limitToFirst, after your orderBy just have it return one:

```
...ref.orderByChild('timestamp').limitToLast(1)
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#limitToFirst

Side note... storing it by time stamp is not ideal as that is not guaranteed to be unique if two users send a message at the same time. Your firebase data would overwrite itself. Even more so that your key doesn't contain milliseconds but just seconds.

Comment: I wasn't able to get `orderByChild('-timestamp')` to work (sorting descending order) so I ended using `limitToLast(1)`, but this got me going in the right direction

Comment: Exactly! It's done lexographically so I should of put limitToLast I will update my answer.